# No qualifying bean found for dependency [**.Clients]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection

I'm trying to develop simple application using spring framework, when I execute the project at eclipse this exception :

**Exception:**

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientDao' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.stockManager.props.dao.Clients]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
May 03, 2017 11:34:23 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientDao' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.stockManager.props.dao.Clients]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.stockManager.props.dao.Clients]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 24 more

May 03, 2017 11:34:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientDao' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.stockManager.props.dao.Clients]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.stockManager.props.dao.Clients]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 24 more
```

**Implementation:**

**Clients:**

```
@Component("clientDao")
public class Clients extends SqlConnectionManager {

    public List<Client> getClients() {

        return jdbc.query("select * from clients", new RowMapper<Client>() {

            public Client mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Client client = new Client();

                client.setClientId(rs.getInt("clientId"));
                client.setClientName(rs.getString("clientName"));
                client.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                client.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                client.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                client.setType(rs.getString("type"));
                return client;
            }

        });
    }

    public List<Client> getClients(String clientName) {

        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        parameters.addValue("clientName", clientName);
        return jdbc.query(
                "select * from clients where clientName = :clientName",
                parameters, new RowMapper<Client>() {

                    public Client mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                            throws SQLException {
                        Client client = new Client();

                        client.setClientId(rs.getInt("clientId"));
                        client.setClientName(rs.getString("clientName"));
                        client.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                        client.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                        client.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                        client.setType(rs.getString("type"));
                        return client;
                    }

                });

    }

    /**
     * get client by PHONE number
     * 
     * @param phone
     * @return
     */
    public List<Client> getClientsByPhoneNumber(String phone) {

        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        parameters.addValue("phone", phone);

        return jdbc.query("select * from clients where phone = :phone",
                parameters, new RowMapper<Client>() {

                    public Client mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                            throws SQLException {
                        Client client = new Client();

                        client.setClientId(rs.getInt("clientId"));
                        client.setClientName(rs.getString("clientName"));
                        client.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                        client.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                        client.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                        client.setType(rs.getString("type"));
                        return client;
                    }

                });

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param client
     * @return
     */
    public boolean create(Client client) {
        BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
                client);
        try {

            return jdbc
                    .update("insert into clients (clientName, address, email, phone, type) "
                            + "values (:clientName, :address, :email, :phone, :type)",
                            params) == 1;
        } catch (InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;

    }


    /**
     * get client by his phone number
     * @param phone
     * @return
     */
    public Client getClient(String phone) {
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("phone", phone);
        return jdbc.queryForObject(
                "select * from clients where phone = :phone", parameters,
                new RowMapper<Client>() {

                    public Client mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                            throws SQLException {
                        Client client = new Client();
                        client.setClientId(rs.getInt("clientId"));
                        client.setClientName(rs.getString("clientName"));
                        client.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                        client.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                        client.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                        client.setType(rs.getString("type"));

                        return client;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Transactional
    public int[] create(List<Client> clients) {
        SqlParameterSource[] params = SqlParameterSourceUtils
                .createBatch(clients.toArray());

        return jdbc.batchUpdate(
                        "insert into clients (clientName,  address, email, phone, type) "
                                + "values (:clientName,  :address, :email, :phone, :type)",
                        params);
    }

}
```

**ClientService:**

```
@Service
public class ClientService {

    private Clients clientDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setClientDao(Clients clientDao){
        this.clientDao = clientDao;
    }

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        clientDao.create(client);
    }

}
```

**ClientController:**

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {


    private ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    public void setService(ClientService service) {
        this.clientService = service;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/doAddClient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAddClient(@Valid Client client ){
        clientService.addClient(client);


        return "order";
    }

}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.ali.taha</groupId>
    <artifactId>stockManagerWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Configuration files:** 
**beans.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="stockManager">
    </context:component-scan>


    <context:property-placeholder
        location="stockManager/props/jdbc.properties" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**dao-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="stockManager.props.dao">
    </context:component-scan>
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/spring" id="dataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
</beans>
```

**security-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">




    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />

    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"
            invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addProduct"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/doAddProduct"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/productsList"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/doOrder"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/cart"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/orderDetails"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addToCart"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/addMoreToCart"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/getOrdersHistory"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/cancelOrder"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/users"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/stockManagerWeb"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/dashboard" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login" />
        </security:session-management>


    </security:http>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.stockManager.beans.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

**service-context:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="stockManagerWeb.net.alitech.service">
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
</beans>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you share your application context.xml as well ?

Comment: Try to remove the "clientDao" from the annotation `@Component("clientDao")` leaving just `@Component`

Comment: Try remove "clientDao" in `@Component` or add `@Qualifier("clientDao")` below `@Autowired`

Comment: If these information didn't solve your problem, please edit and add your configurations files.

Comment: I added configuration files, please ley me know if you want more details.

Comment: I tries all options , any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use @Component instead of @Component("clientDao"). this will register your bean with name "Clients" . Or if you do not want to do this then second options is @Qualifier("clientDao") which you can just put after @Autiwire. like

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("clientDao")
public void setClientDao(Clients clientDao){
    this.clientDao = clientDao;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ClientService and ClientController like below.

ClientService:

```
@Service
public class ClientService {

    private Clients clientDao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("clientDao")
    public void setClientDao(Clients clientDao){
        this.clientDao = clientDao;
    }

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        clientDao.create(client);
    }

}
```

ClientController:

```
    @Controller
public class ClientController {


    private ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("clientService")
    public void setService(ClientService service) {
        this.clientService = service;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/doAddClient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAddClient(@Valid Client client ){
        clientService.addClient(client);


        return "order";
    }

}
```

You have to learn about @Autowired and @Qualifer in Spring.you can read it [here](http://codegeekslab.com/autowiring-using-annotations-spring/).